# In WordPress, "discussion" module is not available for post type with comments support added recently

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WP theme with a few custom post types.

I just recently added support for comments trough the "supports" parameter in the register post type function.

This adds the "quote bubbles" with comment counter on post overview in admin, and also gives me the option to toggle commenting on/off on "quick edit".

However, on the post edit screen the discussion meta box is not available, not even available to enable to the "screen options pane".

It's there for normal 'page' & 'post' posts, and if i change the name of one of my custom post types it appears.

So i guess somewhere it got cached/stuck when i first registrered these post types without comments.

Question is, what can i reset without having to change my post type names?

Answer (score 0):

Allright, feel a bit stupid now. But i just realised ACF had an option "Hide discussion", that was enabled for one of my field groups :/